# More information about <data-source> tag in web.xml

Tags: java, resources, datasource, standards, web.xml

I was looking for something **standard** about the DataSource configuration for a Java EE application, but all I found on the Internet was container specific (example : *context.xml* with Tomcat).

I found [this very rare subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261491) about the **`<data-source>`** tag. See the links inside, it's very interesting. I couldn't find more information in the Sun/Oracle documentation.

So I have a few questions :

1. Does the **`<data-source>`** tag work with all web servers ? (Tomcat,
   JBoss)
2. Multiple resources : Can we have more than one **`<data-source>`**
   tag in the *web.xml* ?
3. Do we have to use the **`<resource-ref>`** tag (for @Resource annotation) in the *web.xml* when we use **`<data-source>`** tag, or is it unnecessary ?
4. When we call the DataSource with "InitialContext" or
   "@Resource", is it the **same instance** for each call ? If yes, is it
   more like EJB Session Bean @Stateless (which could possibly be the same
   instance), or more like EJB Session Bean @Singleton (must be the
   same instance) ?
5. I understand that the **`<data-source>`** tag
   appeared with the Java EE 6 standards, but where can I found more
   informations about it ? Which JSR ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **JSR88 API**'s to view applications that include Java EE 6 Data      Sources.