# External Datasource file in Wildfly 10

Tags: xml, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I want to be able to use **.ds.xml** files as in older versions of Jboss.
Currently we are using **Wildfly 10.0.0** and propably **won't update** any time soon, I searched for quite some time now and it seems that it is currently not possible?

For example I configured an resource adapter and the configuration is in the **standalone.xml** like this:

```
<resource-adapter id="TCPConnector" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <module slot="1.0.0.0" id="com.company.server.TCPConnector"/>
                    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.company.server.jca.tcp.impl.TCPManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/tcp/TcpDevice3" pool-name="TcpDevice3">
                            <config-property name="protocol">
                                MesswertLieferantProtocol
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="port">
                                8000
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="name">
                                terminal2
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="host">
                                192.168.0.165
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="deviceClass">
                                MesswertLieferant
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="timeout">
                                120000
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="enabled">
                                false
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                 </connection-definitions>
             </resource-adapter>
```

Multiple devices would clearly cause a way too big file. We want to keep the standalone.xml clean and coming from Jboss ( some time ago ) we thought of using .ds files to extract that part.

Am I correct that it is not possible anymore? 
Sources I looked through:
[Link 1](https://mirocupak.com/configuring-a-datasource-on-wildfly/) 
[Link 2](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel) 
[Link 3](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Resource+adapters) 
[Link 4](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/deployment/xml/datasource/test-ds.xml) 
[Link 5](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267370)

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to use external .ds.xml files in wildfly 10 to configure stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but deprecated (and not recommended). Check this thread for details:

[Is it possible to use a datasource deployment descriptor with a driver module in Wildfly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582579/is-it-possible-to-use-a-datasource-deployment-descriptor-with-a-driver-module-in)

Comment: Please add your concerns about `*-ds.xml` being deprecated to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4296.