# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException when trying to lookup resource declared in context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I am deploying a WAR to JBoss EAP 7. In my WAR's `META-INF/context.xml` file I have the following:

```
<Context unloadDelay="500000">
    <Resource name="jdbc/sybase/somedb"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:jtds:sybase://localhost:12501/somedb"
          username="username" password="secret"
          validationQuery="select 1"              
          maxActive="2" maxIdle="0" maxWait="-1"/>          
...
```

From my Java code I try to obtain the DataSource doing a:

```
InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext(); 
DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/sybase/somedb" );
```

The exact above code **works** and the name is **found** in the context when I deploy to Tomcat 8 but not when I deploy to JBoss EAP 7. In the latter case I get:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/sybase/somedb -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.env.jdbc.sybase.somedb
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix the above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `META-INF/context.xml` file is a Tomcat deployment descriptor (not defined by the Java EE specification) so it is not seen or parsed by JBoss EAP 7.

There are many alternatives to this including the solution to [is there a standard way to define a JDBC Datasource for Java EE containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279913/is-there-a-standard-way-to-define-a-jdbc-datasource-for-java-ee-containers/16261491#16261491).

If you were to ask RedHat support they would likely recommend that you create the datasource using server administration tools such as the admin console or `jboss-cli.sh`. This decouples your application from the datasource definition so that you can specify environment specific settings (such as pool sizes and hostnames) without repackaging your WAR.file. This method also requires you to deploy the JDBC driver jar separately from your application.