# ActiveJdbc second connection to same database

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, activejdbc

I'm using activejdbc for a Java ee project I have to do for school and I really like it. I do however have a recurring problem whenever I need more than one connection to the same database in one HttpServletRequest.

The scenario is the following:
I have a custom Tag which lists the contents of the shoppingcart of a user which is called on every request, since I placed it in my header.jsp. In this tag I ask activeJdbc for the contents of the shoppingcart of this user. It looks like this:

```
Base.open("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/wpr_webshop", "root", "root");
            Iterator<Record> rIter = shopCart.getAll(Record.class).iterator();


            if (rIter.hasNext()) {
                int shoppingCartTotal = 0;
                out.write("<div class='shoppingcartcontents'>Your cart contains:<br>");

                while (rIter.hasNext()) {
                    Record r = rIter.next();
                    Artist a = r.parent(Artist.class);

                    out.write(a.getString("artist_name") + " - " + r.getString("title") + "<br />");
                    shoppingCartTotal += r.getInteger("price");
                }
                Base.close();
```

Then, in a servlet which renders a jsp that includes the jsp which uses the tag from above, I do additional stuff with activejdbc like normal record selection; also using `Base.open()` on the same database which gives me a

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Cannot open a new connection because existing connection is still on current thread, name: default, connection instance: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2c2552bd. This might indicate a logical error in your application.
```

exception. I get what the problem here is and I'm already really thorough on closing the base connection as soon as I don't require it anymore, I can't however seem to prevent this problem.

I guess a solution to this would be to allow the custom tag, which is called on every request, use a different connection to not conflict with the base connection. Unfortunately I couldn't find any information on how to open a second connection to the same database on the web.

Is this even possible? Or am I just doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is a terrible idea to open a connection in the tag or even the servlet. An entire request should not be opening many connections to the same database, but rather share it on the thread. Remove all `Base.open()/close()` calls from your code and write a simple ServletFilter which will open a connection before the request and close it after.

Here is an example: [ActiveJdbcFilter](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/web/ActiveJdbcFilter.java) -  it uses JNDI, but you can use this code as guidance.

For docs on managing connections, refer to: http://javalite.io/database_connection_management.

On the other note, your code calls `rIter.hasNext()` twice  - is this intentional?

Additionally, here is a better implementation of your loop:

```
List<Record> records  = shopCart.getAll(Record.class).include(Artist.class);

for(Record r: records){    
  Artist a = r.parent(Artist.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, ipolevoy, as always, quite resourceful. I moved the connection to a webfilter, which solved all my issues. The loop was a work in progress, thanks for pointing it out, though. Again, I gotta say I'm quite impressed by ActiveJdbc. Not to mention the great support. Thanks a lot for that, you're making my life as a noob a whole lot better. Best wishes, derelektrischemoench

Comment: @derelektrischemoench you are making great progress, good luck! You might want to upvote my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Base.open` is not recommended when using Java EE, since there is a better mechanism already built in, that of JDBC Connection Pools.See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261491/8707412 for how to configure them. These can then be included in your code with

```
@Resource(name="jdbc:app/myDS")
DataSource ds;
```

You can then get a connection from it with

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: sorry, but your advice is misleading,. ActiveJDBC shares a connection on the current Thread. See http://javalite.io/database_connection_management for more information.