# Custom Property for PGSimpleDataSource in Payara 5 web.xml

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, configuration, payara

I want to configure a data source in Payara 5 using PostgresQL as the database. This is my code from web.xml:

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:global/my_ds</name>
    <class-name>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</class-name>
    <server-name>postgres.host.test</server-name>
    <port-number>0</port-number>
    <database-name>mydb</database-name>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pwd</password>
</data-source>
```

This works fine. However I need to set the current schema on the data source. There is a method on PGSimpleDataSource to do so, so I could do that programmatically. However I'd like to configure the current schema along with the other options. To that end, I tried:

1. Adding another child tag called `<current-schema>my-schema</current-schema>` to the `<data-source>` tag. My IDE complained that this additional tag is not allowed.
2. Adding a property with names `current-schema` and `currentSchema` to the `<data-source>` tag. That was allowed, but had no effect.

So, now I'm looking for the way that actually works.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: did you add a property with names `<currentSchema>my-schema</currentSchema>` or `<name>currentSchema</name><value>my-schema</value>`? Also, would it maybe possible for you to specify the schema in the URL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc

Comment: No worries, I used ```<name>currentSchema</name><value>my-schema</value>``` and ```<name>current-schema</name><value>my-schema</value>```. As there is no URL in this scenario I can't specify the current schema in it. Trying to specify it in the database-name also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [How can I configure JPA for a postgres database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176091/how-can-i-configure-jpa-for-a-postgres-database-schema) suggests the solution is indeed to configure a property like so:

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:global/my_ds</name>
    <class-name>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</class-name>
    <server-name>postgres.host.test</server-name>
    <port-number>0</port-number>
    <database-name>mydb</database-name>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pwd</password>

    <!-- This is the correct property -->
    <property>
        <name>currentSchema</name>
        <value>my-schema</value>
    </property>

</data-source>
```

Comment: So how is this different from what you tried as per the comments above? ;) Did you forget to specify `<property>` tags before or what was the problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the problem was. When I first tried it, it didn't work. When I tried it again, it worked.