# How do I build a J2EE EAR file in RAD using Maven?

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, hudson, rad, ear

Using Rational Application Developer to create a J2EE application, I create a project for my EAR and a project for my WAR - following the usual project structure created by RAD.

So, how do I create a Maven build file that builds the EAR with the WAR inside, etc - ready to deploy. Build needs to work when kicked-off from Hudson.

Answer (score 3):

If your EAR is a standard EAR, then "simply" use the [Maven EAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/). If you need more specific guidance, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: The ear is not exactly a stanard EAR.  It will be a Webshere specific EAR - with the extra ibmconfig directory and assocated Websphere configuration.  

   <dependency>
     <groupId>my.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>WAR</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
 <type>war</type>
     </dependency>

I have the above linked dependency for the WAR file.  Inside RAD, kicking off the EAR build compiles, packages and includes the WAD inside the EAR.  In Hudson - the same script gives an error. "projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between ... introduces to cycle in the graph"

Comment: Formatting does not work in commments - and not enough space to show the complete error.

Comment: @Stevie You can't have cyclic dependencies with Maven but I don't get where you have a cyclic dependency. Please, edit and update your question with the relevant snippets instead of using comments. Also, can you clarify if the content of `ibmconfig` is dynamic or not. It the content is static, this shouldn't be a problem (just in case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060368/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ear-file-and-a-websphere-enhanced-ear/2060743#2060743).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this Java EE development using Rational Application Developer 7.5.5 and Maven - Learn how the powerful open Maven build framework can be integrated with Rational Application Developer 7.5.5's rich set of Java EE 5 development tools- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113607155/RAD_755_MAVEN_0601.pdf?version=1

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experiance with RAD + Maven. But I had tried WSAD + ANT, and I had to use specific WSAD ant tasks to get this done.
So, same would apply for the RAD +  Maven scenario.
I think this may give some hint.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/rad-mojo.html

Sorry, could not provide a precise solution.

Comment: WSAD ant task is not appropriate (I think).  Build needs to be portable - and needs to run from Hudson, not just within RAD - I think this is the basis of my problem.