# Where Should I add deployment.xml

Tags: websphere

I'm using websphere 7 in my web project.
my project is mavenized, and I've some shared libs to add into deployment.xml bu I don't know where to put it.

Can you give me some help please.

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use an "Enhanced EAR" (if not, please clarify your question).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2060743/142446) covers packaging and gives links to using Ant or wsadmin to accomplish the task.